# PostgreSQL 10.3 pg_dumpall fails: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, backup, connectivity, postgresql-10, pg-dump

System: Windows 10 Pro 64bit, Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134. with Postgres 10.3 db server.

I backup my postgres db using the following statements:

```
"C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin\pg_dumpall.exe" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 --schema-only --clean --file=dumpall_schema_clean_20181101.sql

"C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin\pg_dumpall.exe" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 --globals-only --clean --file=dumpall_globals_clean_20181101.sql

"C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin\pg_dumpall.exe" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 --data-only --clean --file=dumpall_data_clean_20181101.sql
```

When running the `data-only` statement I get an error message

> pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table
>   "allwaysDifferentTableName" failed:
>
> PQgetCopyData() failed. pg_dump: Error message from server: server
>   closed the connection unexpectedly
>           This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>           before or while processing the request.
>
> pg_dump: The command was: COPY schema.allwaysDifferentTableName
>   (id, ...)
>   TO stdout; pg_dumpall: pg_dump failed on database "DATABASE", exiting

This seems to happen at random times and tables, sometimes the error comes after a few GB have been backed up, sometimes after 6 TB. Also, the table that appears in the error message is different all the time.

The log file for the time the error happend:

> 2018-11-07 00:52:59 HKT [25088]: [2-1]
>   user=postgres,db=DATABASE,app=pg_dump,client=127.0.0.1 STATEMENT: 
>   COPY schema.allwaysDifferentTableName (id, ...) TO stdout;
>
> 2018-11-07 00:52:59 HKT [25088]: [3-1]
>   user=postgres,db=DATABASE,app=pg_dump,client=127.0.0.1 FATAL: 
>   connection to client lost
>
> 2018-11-07 00:52:59 HKT [25088]: [4-1]
>   user=postgres,db=DATABASE,app=pg_dump,client=127.0.0.1 STATEMENT: 
>   COPY schema.allwaysDifferentTableName (id, ...) TO stdout;
>
> 2018-11-07 00:53:00 HKT [23288]: [1-1]
>   user=postgres,db=postgres,app=pg_dumpall,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  could
>   not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host.

The Postgres server runs on the same physical machine and I am not sure why it has a connection problem. I read, that a virus scanner may cause this problem, so I even turned that off. I also ran `VACCUM ANALYZE` prior to the backup.